# RDP field does not exist in the report provider table

Tags: reporting-services, report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

The error I receive is:

> Could not execute the query. The field(s) SMADispatchSheetReportTmp.1.District do not exist in the report provider table SMADispatchSheetReportTmp.

The District field is in SMADispatchSheetReportTmp table. What steps do I need to take to find the source of this error or to correct it?

Please ask questions if more information is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is one of the 1000 SRSS errors which did not end up in [Troubleshooting Report Definition Issues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731894.aspx).

Using the magic of Google it appears others had [the exact same problem](http://www.pedia.dk/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=25).

Go restart your SSRS service.

Comment: Thanks. It did come across to me as a common problem. My google skills  aren't very sharp yet.